# Force mounting, bypassing fsck

Tags: mount, fsck, dmesg

When I try to mount some SD card, it fails and `dmesg` displays:

```
[  124.121735] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted.
                              Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

**How to force to mount the SD card anyway, in read-only mode, and avoid going to fsck?**

Comment: What command did you use to try to mount it in the first place? Did you try simply adding `-r` to that command?

Comment: @Celada I tried `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/` or `mount -r /dev/sdb1 /media/`

Answer (score 2):

There is not a `-o force` [mount option](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for (v)FAT. A safe alternative is to image the sdcard and then do an `fsck` on the image.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=~/sdcard.image
dosfsck -l -w -a -r -v -t ~/sdcard.image
mount -t vfat -o loop,ro ~/sdcard.image /mnt/sdcard
```